# how to update device position in estimote indoor location when application is killed or Background

Tags: ios, estimote

I have to use estimote indoor location SDK

i have to detect my device is enter or exit of the indoor location area when my app is killed or background

please tell me guys how to tackle this scenario.

Thanks

```
[ESTConfig setupAppID:@"" andAppToken:@""];

locationManger = [[EILIndoorLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManger.delegate = self;


EILRequestFetchLocation *fetchLocationreq = [[EILRequestFetchLocation alloc]initWithLocationIdentifier:@"test-2c5"];

[fetchLocationreq sendRequestWithCompletion:^(EILLocation * _Nullable location, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (location != nil) {

        locationEILL = location;
        locationView.showTrace = YES;
        locationView.rotateOnPositionUpdate = YES;

        [locationView drawLocation:location];
        [locationManger startMonitoringForLocation:locationEILL];
        [locationManger startPositionUpdatesForLocation:locationEILL];
    }

}];

}

#pragma mark - EILLindoorlocationmanager Delegate

- (void)indoorLocationManager:(EILIndoorLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdatePosition:(EILOrientedPoint *)position
             withAccuracy:(EILPositionAccuracy)positionAccuracy
               inLocation:(EILLocation *)location
{

NSLog(@"x: %5.2f, y: %5.2f, orientation: %3.0f", position.x,position.y,position.orientation);

[locationView updatePosition:position];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be done if you are asking for always authorization. 
in your case`beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`

reference: http://developer.estimote.com/ibeacon/tutorial/part-2-background-monitoring/

Check if you grant the permission correctly in you app setting page. It should be always not when in use.

Comment: Already added in code,but not working.
You have to use estimote indoor location SDK?

Comment: Please show us the code. If you set up NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist and the user grant permission, it should work.  edited my ans for more info

Answer (score 0):

When your app is killed use [HeroIcon](https://cloud.estimote.com/#/apps/add/hero-icon) for estimote app.
As documentations says

> HeroIcon
>
> Uses: beacon monitoring, suggested apps Monitor for a beacon to have
>   iOS show the app's icon on the lock screen ("suggested apps" feature
>   introduced in iOS 8) when in range of the beacon.

Sorce Code:
https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/tree/master/Examples/objective-c/HeroIcon

Comment: i have to use indoor location sdk...
i have to edit question with code please check.